# WordPress Widget Area Links Only Work From Home Page

Tags: hyperlink, widget, area

WordPress Widget Area Links Only Work From Home Page

Below is the code in wootique theme footer 1 widget area.  The links works fine from the home page but when any of the links is click again from the page that it landed on the homepage url is repeated in the url section of the page and it says page not found. This happens when you click any of the links.

Here is the code that I placed in the widget footer 1 area:

```
 <div id="parent-footer">
        <a href ="XXXXXXXXXX.com/product-gallery/"><div id="first">Product      Gallery</div></a>
        <a href ="XXXXXXXXXX.com/blog/"><div id="second">Blog</div></a>
<a href ="XXXXXXXXXX.com/returns/">         <div id="third">Return     Policy</div>
    </div></a>

<style>
              #parent-footer {
           width: 200%; 
        white-space: nowrap;
              }

             #parent-footer div{
             display: inline-block;
             width: 33.3%;
             color: #5BB191;
             margin-left: 105px;
             padding:  -60px;
          }


             #first{
                margin-right: 20px;
          }  
       </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the url is repeated like www.xxx.com/something/www.xxx.com/something the problem could be that it is interpreting the url as relative. Add http:// (or https if you are running on a secure link) to the url.